# CUDA fails after resume

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, cuda, blender

CUDA (in this case Blender) works fine after clean boot, but upon resume from suspend errors with this from the CUDA client:

```
CUDA cuInit: Unknown error
```

and this in dmesg:

```
NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-36c9238a-2bc1-8ada-dcbb-17f6c478587e
NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 31, Ch 00000006, engmask 00000104, intr 10000000
```

This has been happening ever since an update to NVidia drivers (not sure which and Ubuntu doesn't keep old versions in their repos so I don't think I can test), and has been occurring consistently after every suspend/resume cycle

System Info:

```
Kubuntu (Ubuntu) 16.04
NVidia GTX 970
nvidia-367 (367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get one year old drivers at the NVidia website. The oldest certified one available there is [this one](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/97644/en-us), (please note this is for 32bit Linux, not sure if your distribution is 64bit in which case you need [that one](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/97645/en-us)).

I find NVidia drivers are notoriously unreliable on Linux, especially when it comes to handling hardware interrupts, but of course if you want to do CUDA you have to rely on them.  Just for display purposes I find the Open Source Nouveau drivers much more stable and perfectly adequate these days.

Comment: Agreed, uninstall the driver and get an older one.